# Python How to count a series with multiple items in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

```
f = open("routeviews-rv2-20181110-1200.pfx2as", 'r')
#read file into array, ignore first 6 lines
lines = loadtxt("routeviews-rv2-20181110-1200.pfx2as", dtype='str', 
delimiter="\t", unpack=False)
#convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(lines,columns=['IPPrefix', 'PrefixLength', 'AS'])
series = df['AS'].astype(str).str.replace('_', ',').str.split(',')
arr = numpy.array(list(chain.from_iterable(series)))
ASes= pd.Series(numpy.bincount(arr))
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '31133_65500,65501'

I want to count each time an item appears in col AS. However some lines have multiple entries that need to be counted.

Refer to: [Python Find max in dataframe column to loop to find all values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231776/python-find-max-in-dataframe-column-to-loop-to-find-all-values)

Txt file: http://data.caida.org/datasets/routing/routeviews-prefix2as/2018/11/

But that cannot count line 67820 below.

```
    Out[94]: df=
              A                 B       C
0             1.0.0.0           24  13335
1             1.0.4.0           22  56203
2             1.0.4.0           24  56203
3             1.0.5.0           24  56203
              ...          ...    ...
67820    1.173.142.0            24  31133_65500,65501
              ...          ...    ...
778719  223.255.252.0           24  58519
778720  223.255.254.0           24  55415
```

The _ is not a typo, that is how it appears in the file.

```
Desired output.
1335     1
...     ..
31133    1
...     ..
55415    1 
...     ..
56203    3
...     ..
58159    1
...     ..
65500    1
65501    1
...     ..
```

Comment: Please, put the desired output. More details needes to describe your program

Comment: "I would expect" is desired output. I want to count occurrences of each number in col A.

Answer (score 1):

#### [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) + [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) + [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

You can replace `_` with `,`, split and then chain before using `np.bincount`:

```
from itertools import chain

series = df['A'].astype(str).str.replace('_', ',').str.split(',')
arr = np.array(list(chain.from_iterable(series))).astype(int)

print(pd.Series(np.bincount(arr)))

0     0
1     0
2     2
3     4
4     1
5     6
6     1
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: .astype(int) have error OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
.astype('int64') gave ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
any suggesitons?

Comment: @JimHubbard, Works fine for me, with the data you've provided (which, admittedly, doesn't include types). You can try providing a [mcve], see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: I know, that was a sample. My file is Length: 778721..with numbers similar in magnitude

Comment: @JimHubbard, Yup, it's tough to help without representative data. If you can find out the row that's causing problems, it'll give me a chance of being able to debug.

Comment: sorry about that. I provided the actual df above. I did not consider length in my previous example. Note it is now col C, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I still see no reason why my code shouldn't work given your data. It would be helpful if you could debug and isolate the *single row* causing you problems.

Comment: I have been playing with it all day. I can not isolate it I tried debugging and got lost in the layers. I attached a link in the question with the text file(routeviews-rv2-20181110-1200). Note the updated code.

Comment: any new suggestions?